# How to install Adobe Digital Editions

Tags: wine, adobe, ebooks, drm

How can I install [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/) on Ubuntu?

I've read that this is possible using Wine, but I can't download [the installer from the Adobe page](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/) (as this installer is an online flash installer and requires Windows).

(I need to open the book I have purchased which is currently in `.acsm` format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clue was in the text underneath the install box:

> If you have trouble installing Digital Editions, see the [installation TechNote](http://www.adobe.com/go/kb403051).

See the "Manually install Adobe Digital Editions for Windows" section. That has a direct link to download an .exe setup file.

I won't link it from here as they will probably update the link in time.

Answer (score 7):

I've been through a process of installing, uninstalling and reinstalling various versions of Adobe Digital Editions (ADE). There is useful information on which versions of ADE will work on which versions of Wine at the WineHQ website. I found the options below worked for installing  ADE on an Ubuntu 14.04LTS system (32-bit).

For all these options, I was able to open some acsm files and download related ebooks. However, only ADE 4.0 allowed me to download ebooks from Google Play that I required. Attempting to download these Google Play ebooks produced a 2038 error on ADE 1.7 and an “E_STREAM_ERROR” on ADE 3.0. I suspect this is due to recent changes in DRM.

INSTALLING ADE 1.7 --- Install Wine and WineTricks (you may need to add the Wine ppa – see https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu). Open WineTricks. In the first dialog box take option “Install an app”. On the second dialog box, take option “adobe_diged”. WineTricks will do the rest. Voila! Note that there are numerous older posts in forums that recommend ADE V1.7 over V2.0 and V3.0.

INSTALLING ADE 3.0 --- You'll need Wine and Winetricks for this too (see above for their installation), but the process is a bit more involved. You need to download and install dotnet35sp1 and windowscodecs before running the ADE installation exe. This can be done by opening a terminal and entering this command:

```
$ winetricks -q dotnet35sp1 windowscodecs
```

INSTALLING ADE 4.0 --- This option also requires Wine and WineTricks but it requires more advanced versions and the process is even more involved. Nonetheless, there are very comprehensive instructions at: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30928 – follow this link and find the instructions under the comment titled, “How to install ADE-4.xx on *ubuntu-14.04* step by step in a console”.

Comment: Awesome! I had to upgrade my ADE from 1.7 to 4.X. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm answering how to install Adobe Digital Editions 2.0.1 (which I needed because of the old-fashioned encryption they used before version 3) for Debian testing ("bookworm" as I am writing this answer). Here are the installation steps I have used, which should be quite the same for any recent Ubuntu distribution:

```
sudo apt install wine winetricks
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet35sp1 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet35sp1 winetricks -q corefonts
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet35sp1 winetricks -q dotnet35sp1
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet35sp1 wine ADE_2.0_Installer.exe
cd $HOME/winedotnet35sp1/drive_c/Program\ Files/Adobe/Adobe\ Digital\ Editions\ 2.0/
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/winedotnet35sp1 wine ./DigitalEditions.exe
```

As I can remember, the installer yielded an error to me at the end of its process, but the piece of software worked fine, then.

Maybe I had to add a 32-bit architecture to my system, thanks to `dpkg --add-architecture i386`, to download the correct packages but I took me so much trials to make this piece of software working that I could not tell whether this is necessary or not. Anyway, as far as I know, a multi-architecture environment is managed differently under Ubuntu.

#### Source

https://patdavid.net/2018/05/installing-adobe-digital-editions-on-linux-with-wine/ (where a link to the 2.0.1 ADE installer can be found as well)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I gave all the steps I have used (even if some may be useless); I gave the exact commands I have used, step by step and I also gave the online documentation I have used to set up my own solution. What do you expect more, @Community?