# Transfert my legally borrowed e-books to my Kobo e-reader

Tags: wine, adobe-digital-editions

Our municipal library sends a *.acsm file by mail when we borrow a e-book, but I'm fed up with having to bother my wife to use her Windows account and we must reboot 'tween nix and doze.
Adobe digital editions needs Wine and .Net35SP1.
So Wine is installed, but the .Net35SP1 installer (dotnetfx35setup.exe) does not connect to download the needed files.
Is the server down or is there another and easier way to install ADE?
I've been trying all weekend.

Comment: see this https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2021/07/download-acsm-files-in-linux-without-using-adobe-digital-editions/

Comment: Old but possibly relevant: https://askubuntu.com/q/92444/243321

Comment: @TalaatEtman That is a very useful link. Please post an answer based on it, if you like.

Comment: This looks like a great solution, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

**Download ACSM files in Linux - without using Adobe Digital Editions!**

There are a few limitations, but nothing too serious:

- Only ePub is supported.
- No PDF Command line only.
- Alpha quality software. It works - but is a bit finickity

You can compile the code yourself, but I just [downloaded the pre-built binaries.](http://indefero.soutade.fr/p/libgourou/downloads/)

On Ubuntu needed to `sudo apt install libzip-dev`

Once you've unzipped the download, cd into it and run:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PWD
```

Then

```
./adept_activate -u youremail@example.com -p SuperStrongPassword
```

Use the same credentials as you do in Adobe Digital Editions. You can just use the `-u` flag and type your password in at the prompt - but I couldn't get that to work. The `-p` flag worked fine.

After a few seconds, you'll see:

```
youremail@example.com fully signed and device activated in /home/you/libgourou_utils_0.3.1/./.adept
```

Then run:

```
./acsmdownloader -f whatever.acsm
```

After a few moments, you'll see:

```
Created whatever.epub
```

That's it! Your file is downloaded and you can read the ePub.

Note: If you try to download a PDF, you'll get an error saying:

```
Exception code : 0x5007
Message : whatever.epub
```

You can rename the file back to .pdf, but it will still be encrypted.

source: [Download ACSM files in Linux - without using Adobe Digital Editions!](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2021/07/download-acsm-files-in-linux-without-using-adobe-digital-editions/)

Comment: I also had to do `ln -s libgourou.so libgourou.so.0.8.1` in the downloaded directory.

Comment: download and conversion to epub worked fine. But my e-reader tels me to authorize the e-book with ADE. So I do ''adept_remove -f my_e-book.epub'' and I get ''invalid zip file''

Comment: I have saved Adobe credentials

Comment: @Rooman try  to convert by this https://ebook.online-convert.com/convert/epub-to-pdf

Comment: @Talaat, tried that and got a conversion error with no details., all very strange.

Comment: @Rooman Once I converted epub manually by extracting it, and then I got the form of web pages that I converted to PDF and merged them into one file